# Wrapping sub-menu items with div - WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In WordPress I am trying to wrap  around the items that are in my sub menu list . I've written the HTML as I want it to appear, but how do I put this into wp_nav_menu()?

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="has_children"><a>Games</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <div class="column"> <!-- this line needs adding -->
        <li>
          <h4>Games</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Game 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Game 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a function

   ```
   class Walker_Nav_Pointers extends Walker_Nav_Menu
   {
       function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() )
       {
           $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
           $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
           $output .= "\n<div class=\"column\">\n";
       }
       function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() )
       {
           $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
           $output .= "$indent</ul>\n".($depth ? "$indent</div>\n" : "");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Wherever you're calling your nav menu, add this to the existing
   arguments:

   ```
   <?php
    $navArgs = array('walker' => new Walker_Nav_Pointers());
    wp_nav_menu($navArgs);
   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First open your theme’s functions.php file and paste the following code:

```
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

And this would make two menu options appear, header menu and extra menu

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
      'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

Once you have pasted this code, It should add as an option under the “Pages” widget on the Menu management page so the user can simply check it off as an item to add to their custom menu.

**Display Menus on Theme**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
```

**Menus Panel**

**Appearance -> Menus** panel in your site admin and use the GUI menu creator on this admin panel to put your menu(s) together.

Comment: Hi Darren, thanks for the answer but I don't see where <div class="column"> would be inserted immediately after the .sub-menu <ul>

Comment: Missed that,  div is not allowed as a direct child of ul. Whenever you're in doubt, validate your page with W3C